# False в СИ

Tags: c

У меня функция должна возвращать все числа, включая ноль. Но может ещё возвращать false. Как мне отличать 0 от false? Пробовал NULL, но оказалось что это тоже самое что и 0. Как мне быть?

Comment: Почему не работает:   
return (test_dy) {false,NULL};
Пишет: "error C2143: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед "{""

Comment: @mctrane: 

* а как вы определили `test_dy`?
* какой у вас компилятор?

Comment: typedef struct test_dy { bool valid; double num; } test_dy;  
Микрософт Студия СИ++ 2012

Comment: @mctrane: Для VS 2012 попробуйте так:

    typedef struct response_t
    {
        int valid;
        int number;
    } response_t;

    response_t half(int n)
    {
        response_t r = { !(n & 1), n >> 1 };
        return r;
    }

К сожалению, VS 2012 не полностью поддерживает современный стандарт C.

Comment: спасибо. А, что даже нельзя задавать так?:  
test_dy r;  
r = {false,NULL};

Comment: @mctrane: В компиляторах, поддерживающих новый стандарт, можно так:

    r = (test_dy) { .valid = false, .num = 0 };

Но в VS 2012 так нельзя из-за устаревшего диалекта C. Зато можно так:

    test_dy r;
    r.valid = false;
    r.num = 0;

Comment: понял, спасибо. Постоянно меня микрософт бесит всё больше и больше. Вообще нормальные люди может на другом компиляторе кодят?

Comment: @mctrane: Ну, по части стандартов, особенно C, обычно выбирают gcc или clang. Но к ним «в нагрузку» обычно идёт linux (или Mac). Компилятор C от Microsoft, однако, придётся использовать, если вы привязаны к платформе (из-за отсутствия бинарной совместимости между различными компиляторами).

Такие дела.

---
А вообще, в тред призывается @avp :-)

Comment: Если интересно мое мнение, то обычно я использую дополнительный аргумент в функции (адрес поля для ошибки). Например, в простейшем случае будет что-то вроде:

     int add(int a1, int a2, int *overflow);

Ну, а в более практической плоскости, например:

    /*
      Длина строки с utf-8 в символах (UCS).
    
      Передаем адрес начала и размер в байтах. Если размер равен нулю, то считаем до U+0000
      При ошибке (неправильный utf-8) в *err передаем смещениие в байтах + 1 (если все ОК, то *err == 0)
     */
    int utf8_len (const char *utf, int n, int *err);

И не забывайте про `errno`.

Comment: @avp: я думал, вы прокомментируете поддержку стандартов С у Майкрософтовских компиляторов, ну и вообще выбор платформы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы, наверное, программировали на PHP до C?

На C делается по-другому: у переменной есть определённый тип, либо число, либо `_Bool` (это такое в современных версиях C название для `bool`; в старых версиях вместо него используют просто `int`).

Например, вы можете возвращать структуру:

```
typedef struct response_t { _Bool valid; int number; } response_t;
```

Пример:

```
response_t half(int n)
{
    return (response_t) { .valid = !(n & 1), .number = n >> 1 };
}
```

Полный пример: http://ideone.com/Cd8lbs

Comment: Ага, вот только Вы забили добавить немного. Типа bool нет в С. [Варианты решения](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921539/using-boolean-values-in-c).

Comment: да, на php)) Структуры у нас далеко ещё. А как возвращать структуру? Может тогда массив проще?

Comment: @KoVadim: `_Bool` есть :-)

Comment: @mctrane: написал небольшой пример: http://ideone.com/DXuheP

Comment: Ааа, понял что такое структура. Грубо говоря это собственный тип переменной. Спасибооо. Крууто, вот это я понимаю, отличная вещь эти структуры

Comment: Ага, это типа класса в PHP, только без методов, лишь с полями.

Comment: @VladD Да ну его нафиг, этот Си. На перле такие фокусы делаются на раз.

Comment: на перле это делается через возврат списка, что по факту та же структура. Только кода чуточку меньше. Но вот только скорость...

Comment: @KoVadim на перле есть значение undef (неопределённое). Но бывают фокусы и покруче. В DBO-какой-то результатом query является количество строк результата, undef (кажется) -- ошибка. В случае результата 0 строк возврается (возвращалось) 1E0, которое в арифметическом выражении == 0, а в логическом -- истина. Перл, однако.

Comment: undef конечно хорош, но обычно хочется ещё знать причину. Естественно, в перле в данном случае можно использовать `$!` (аналог `errno` в других языках).

Comment: @alexlz: C всё-таки низкоуровневый язык, практически ассемблер. А ТС хочет по сути стандартный [Option](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Maybe).

Comment: @VladD Ну так кто мешает? В конце-то концов есть Ocalm & F#, нафига над Це-то издеваться?

Comment: @alexlz: думаю, тут играют внешние соображения. Например, начальник не знает функциональных языков, или считает, что на C всё равно быстрее (а со сложностью пусть программист борется сам, за это ему и зарплату платят). Ну или программисту легче написать на C и сегодня сдать, а не выучить (допустим) Scala и сдать позже.

Comment: @VladD Так это же хорошо! Правда может быть немного тяжеловато морально, но зато не напрягая головы можно вырваться в передовики. По количеству строк/операторов/мегабайтов исходников. Правда потом, "когда автор уедет на свою историческую родину -- Канаду", кому-то достанется сопровождать это счастье.

Answer (score 6):

false в си нет. а 0 эквивалетный NULL  в большинстве вариантов реализаций компилятора. Поэтому 0, NULL и false (в условиях) никак не отличить.

Но есть решение. Вместо целого возвращать структуру. Вот такую например:

```
struct result {
    int result;
    int error_code;
}
```

после этого все заметно упростится.

Comment: Да, структура - достаточно хорошее решение. Можно, правда, еще и отрицательные числа(как сигнализаторы ошибок) возвращать, если, конечно же, ТС имеет ввиду множество чисел от 0 включительно.

Comment: @0xFFh: ТС написал «все числа», да и решение со структурой более идеологически чистое.

Comment: к сожалению возможны любые числа(